es posible Compartir llave Foranea relacion M:1
Buen dia, tengo una duda, estoy haciendo un sistema de seleccion de programas de servicio social, tengo conflictos y/o dudas en dos tabas en especificos, una se llama servicio y otra cupos, hay un formulario en web que me inserta correctamente datos en servicio y me genera su ID bien.
Aqui el detalles es en cupo, hay muchos cupos o vacantes para un mismo programa, varian por carrera, ¿Es posible hacer el registro de cupos uno por uno dependiendo de los requisitos y que esos pertenezcan al mismo servicio, es decir que compartan la misma FK?
Adjunto como es la relacion en diagrama: [![Diagrama de la Base de Datos]!]


que tienen que ver en tu problema php, jquery, ajax y json??? por favor, usa las etiquetas que corresponden...

respecto de tu problema, yo no veo ningun problema. vos que problema ves?

Quizás necesitas más tablas de las que tienes. Cada entidad debe ser una tabla independiente y por lo que dices, parece que Carrera es una buena candidata, y en la otra tabla hay un Departamento en la misma tabla que Programa (que supongo debe ser el nombre del servicio), lo cual no me suena correcto. Lee sobre el modelo entidad relación.

Parece que lo que necesitas es una relación muchos a muchos, la cual se implementa creando una tabla asociativa, que en este caso tendrá los IDs de servicio social y de cupos o de cuentas (porque tampoco queda claro todo el contexto en el planteamiento de la pregunta). Creo que esta respuesta podría ayudarte a clarificar el asunto.
